# SonarQube issue: Make sure that decompressing this archive file is safe

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have code that creates 3 files from 3 strings and zips it into the archive like:

```
private static async Task<byte[]> CreateArchive(CertificateCredentials certificate)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
        {
            await Add(archive, "certificate.der", certificate.CertificateContent);
            await Add(archive, "issuing_ca.der", certificate.IssuingCACertificateContent);
            await Add(archive, "private_key.der", certificate.PrivateKeyContent);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();

        async Task Add(ZipArchive zipArchive, string filename, string content)
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(filename);
            using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(content)))
            using (Stream zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
            {
                await originalFileStream.CopyToAsync(zipEntryStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In SonarQube report I got Critical Security Hotspot at this line

```
using (Stream zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
```

with message:

> Make sure that decompressing this archive file is safe

https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp?search=Expanding%20archive%20files%20is%20security-sensitive

How can I fix that? It looks like secure for me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check the "Ask Yourself Whether" section in the rule details?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes, any problems?

Comment: So then you find yourself not at risk. You can mark this issue as a false positive and you are ready. SonarQube is doing its best to detect issues with not too much false positives.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Sorry but I do not understand what you mean. how it can help me to fix warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding security related rules you can find the actual documentation [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/security-rules/). You can read in the "What to expect from security-related rules" that the chance of false positives is greater and that a human should have a look at it when an issue is raised. So, given the example, it is well possible that this issue can be identified as a false positive and no code change is needed. In the user guide you can find [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/issues/) how to handle reported issues. In the "Automatic Issue Assignment" section (Technical Review) you can read how to mark an issue as a false-positive (this requires Administer Issues permission on the project) using the SonarQube UI. This prevents future issue reporting on this code. When there are a lot of issues reported based on this rule you could decide to disable the rule or lower its priority. An other possiblity is to [narrow the focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) by ignore Issues in a few Blocks for example. It all depends on the type of project and the project/security requirements.

EDIT:

The rule warns for the following issues:

- CVE-2018-1263: It is possible to construct a (external) zip with files that, when extracted, will be placed outside the extraction directory. When adding a file to a zip, the file will be identified inside the zip by a filename (including a path if needed). The CVE database does not mention an example yet.
- CVE-2018-16131: It is possible to create a (extrenal) zip that, when extracted will consume all the memory available and this will crash the host ('Zip Bomb'). The CVE database is pointing to [this](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/2137) issue where someone succeeds to exploit this issue.

SonarQube doesn't want to know how *ZipArchive* is implemented. It is quite possible that, when adding a new item to a zip, the original Zip if first extracted exposing the issues above. Your are creating and using a (in memory, but that is not very relevant) zip archive in your own code, not using **any external provided zip file** so both are of no issue here if you trust the .Net implementation of the methods used.

The SonarQube documentation is also pointing to [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/IDS04-J.+Safely+extract+files+from+ZipInputStream) Java example containing a security compliant solution. It is quite possible that even then SonarQube will warn you.

Comment: I need explanation why my code is insecure because it is unclear for me. Rule says: Validate the full path of the extracted file against the full path of the directory where files are expanded! I don't have any path here, so I want to know why it is insecure in my case. Can you explain?

Comment: @Chebur I have updated the answer. Can someone explain why the answer is downgraded?